# Is there a better way to re-use plots Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The below code block (A) solves my overall problem of being able to re-use plots, but i'm wondering if there is a better way (one that doesn't involve creating a function for each plt.plot, as is shown below.

Code block A:

```
import maptplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create a function just to call the plt.plot
def first_plot(): plt.plot(x,y) 
first_plot()
# Now i can just show the first plot
plt.show()

def second_plot(): plt.plot(x,z)

first_plot() # instead of plt.plot(x,y)
second_plot() # instead of plt.plot(x,z)
# now i can show both plots
plt.show()
```

if the plots are complicated:

```
plot.plot(lots of details)
```

and their are many:

```
plots = [first,second,third,fourth,...]
```

I would think this would be advantageous because it avoids code re-use.

However, creating a function just to call plt.plot() indicates to me their might be a better way.what i would like to be doing is something like

```
first_plot = plt.plot(x,y)
first_plot()
#now i want to show just the first plot
plt.show() # first call

second_plot = plt.plot(x,z)
# now i want to show them together combined
first_plot() 
second_plot()
plt.show() # second call
```

But this doesn't seem to work/e.g the second call to plt.show() wouldn't produce the first plot. (even if you unpack first_plot (which in reality, from code block B, is actual a list):

```
In [17]: first_plot
Out[17]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fd33ac8ff50>]
```

This cannot be used to produce the plot again in anyway I can see. This might be because of the relationship between plt.show and plt.plot, which i don't fully understand. Plt.plot seems to put the plot in a que, that then plt.show pops out. However,
 plt.shows description talks about a blocking and unblocking mode and interactive and non-interactive mode:

```
show(*args, **kw)
    When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display all
    figures and return to the ipython prompt.

    In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until
    the figures have been closed; in interactive mode it has no
    effect unless figures were created prior to a change from
    non-interactive to interactive mode (not recommended).  In
    that case it displays the figures but does not block.

    A single experimental keyword argument, *block*, may be
    set to True or False to override the blocking behavior
    described above.
```

Which i don't understand. But regardless of how i call plt.show() vs plt.show(False) (blocking?) it doesn't seem to have an impact e.g the output is the same in the context of code block A and B.

So put another way, is there a way to select which plots created to show/overlay at different points in the code?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens? What is the full text of any errors or tracebacks? What is the desired output? And do you understand the consequences of assigning the results of a call to `plot()` to a variable?

Comment: I re-worded the question to hopefully be more clear. "it doesnt work" meant that the first plot doesn't show with the second call to plt.show(). The desired output, would be the same output from code block A, but the desired input (my code) wouldn't need a to create a function for each plot(). No, i don't understand the consequences of assigning the result of a call to plt() to a variable, and did that purely to demonstrate the cleaner code i would like to be producing. Maybe another way to handle this is to change what plt.show renders and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However awkward, it seems the best way to "re-use" plots as described in my question is to do as I original suggested and put it inside a function.

```
def some_plot(): return plot(x,y)
```

and then if you want to re-use the plot simply call the function again:

```
some_plot()
```